# Problema al leer objectos enviados por Socket Java

Tags: java, socket

Tengo un problema al enviar un objeto de una clase por socket. Tengo la clase `hiloservidor` la cual se encarga de ejecutar hilos cada vez que llegue una petición.

```
private Socket ss;
private int counter;

public hiloservidor(Socket i,int c){
    this.ss=i;
    this.counter=c;
}

@Override
public void run(){

    try{
        boolean done = false;
        System.out.println("hola cliente "+counter);


        while(!done){
            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(ss.getInputStream()); 
            ClaseServidor cla = (ClaseServidor) entrada.readObject();--> aquí está el problema se queda en un cliclo infinito en esta linea.

            System.out.println("Datos del servidor de descarga recibido");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

y tengo la clase cliente:

```
public class SerDes{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {

            boolean salir=false;

            int i = 1;
            Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4890);
            ArrayList<String>coleccion = new ArrayList<String>();
            coleccion.add("Libro1");
            coleccion.add("Libro2");
            coleccion.add("Libro3");
            coleccion.add("Libro4");
            coleccion.add("Libro5");
            coleccion.add("Libro6");

            ClaseServidor miServidor = new ClaseServidor(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),15253,coleccion);

            System.out.println(miServidor.getColeccion());*/

            while(salir==false){
                ObjectOutputStream msgToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
                msgToServer.writeObject(miServidor);
                msgToServer.flush();
                System.out.println("datos del servidor enviados");
                salir = true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

la clase `ClaseServidor` que está en los dos proyectos

```
public class ClaseServidor implements Serializable{
    String ip;
    int puerto;
    ArrayList<String> coleccion;

    public ClaseServidor(){}

    public ClaseServidor(String ip, int puerto, ArrayList<String> coleccion) {
        super();
        this.ip = ip;
        this.puerto = puerto;
        this.coleccion = coleccion;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }
    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }
    public int getPuerto() {
        return puerto;
    }
    public void setPuerto(int puerto) {
        this.puerto = puerto;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getColeccion() {
        return coleccion;
    }
    public void setColeccion(ArrayList<String> coleccion) {
        this.coleccion = coleccion;
    }
}
```

El problema está cuando leo los objetos en la clase hiloservidor, se queda en un loop leyendo el objeto no se porque. Lo probé enviando un String y funciona pero con objetos no. La clase `ClaseServidor` está en los dos proyectos y está serializada.

Comment: ¿intentaste cerrar el flujo de salida y entrada? `msgToServer.close();`

Comment: si ya lo intenté y nada

Comment: @Antonio Ya solucionastes

Answer (score 1):

Después de ver tu código un poco creo que el problema es que la variable `done` nunca toma el valor `true`. La inicializas a `false` en el ámbito del bloque `try` y no veo el sitio donde la cambias.

Comment: cierto amigo me falto colocar esa línea, pero el problema era que  en la clase cliente no cerraba el socket cuando lo enviaba. Gracias igual.

Comment: Pero bueno, aunque cerras esa línea la tienes que poner si o si